# Laravel 8 "fortify" redirect not working after registration on production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, fortify, laravel-authentication

I have setup a role base authentication for admin and users to be redirected to a different route after registration and login which perfectly well on my local machine but when I deploy to production, it redirects to /home which I have not declared in my web.php

FortifyServiceProvider.php

```
$this->app->singleton(
  LoginResponseContract::class,
  LoginResponse::class
);
$this->app->singleton(
  TwoFactorLoginResponseContract::class,
  TwoFactorLoginResponse::class
);
```

loginResponse.php

```
public function toResponse($request)
{
  $role = \Auth::user()->role_id;

  if ($request->wantsJson()) {
     return response()->json(['two_factor' => false]);
  }

  $home = $role == 1 ? '/admin' : '/account';
  return redirect()->intended($home);
}
```

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
public const ACCOUNT = '/account';
public const ADMIN = '/admin';
```

CreateNewUser.php

```
$user = User::create([
   'name' => $input['name'],
   'username' => $input['username'],
   'email' => $input['email'],
   'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
   'role_id' => 2,
   'referrer_id' => $referrer->id ?? null,
]);

$user->notify(new WelcomeEmail($user));
return $user;
```

Please any help would be appreciated, I have been stuck for the past two days 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe the version of php of your local and production is different
so some php version does not work with this form of IF
use this way:

```
public function toResponse($request)
{
  $role = \Auth::user()->role_id;

  if ($request->wantsJson()) {
     return response()->json(['two_factor' => false]);
  }
  if($role == 1){
     $home = '/admin';
  }else{
     $home ='/account';
  }
  
  return redirect()->to($home);
}
```

Comment: yes PHP version is different. on my local machine its PHP8 and on the server it's PHP7.4. Although I made changes like you suggested and ran ```php artisan optimize``` but it still directs me to ```/home``` after registration

Comment: use return redirect::to($home);